# Probability theory in machine learning

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, machine-learning

I have read that probability model of a random phenomenon given by, for example, probability density function (PDF) or cumulative distribution function (CDF) can be used to develop a machine learning algorithm for that phenomenon. However, I could not find how is this done. See the following paragraph for this [web page](https://deepai.org/machine-learning-glossary-and-terms/probability-density-function), for example.

> A Probability Density Function is a tool used by machine learning algorithms and neural networks that are trained to calculate probabilities from continuous random variables. For example, a neural network that is looking at financial markets and attempting to guide investors may calculate the probability of the stock market rising 5-10%. To do so, it could use a Probability Density Function in order to calculate the total probability that the continuous random variable range will occur.

Consider the following example PDF.

$$
f_X(x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{k}{x} & 2<x\le6 \\
0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$

Can someone elaborate how this PDF can be used to develop pseudo code for a machine learning algorithm? I will also be interested in a short article or quick tutorial that explains the usage of a PDF in the development of a machine learning algorithm with the help of some examples.

If my question is not very clear or there are gaps, please help me improve it.

Comment: This is very vague.  What is it you want your machine to learn about?  In what way is it connected to this density function?

Comment: @lulu I am new to  machine learning. Therefore, you can use any example to connect the PDF to a phenomenon of your choice, and then explain how the machine will learn to decide something about that phenomenon.

Comment: But...a specific probability distribution is more likely to be a *conclusion* than an *assumption*.   That is, a good machine model of a process might be a distribution (or a collection of them).  If you know the underlying distribution at the start, what is there to model?   It's natural, maybe even inevitable, to make some assumptions regarding the nature of the underlying distributions.  One has to start somewhere.

Comment: As you said, a machine model uses a distribution. My question is, how this distribution is used by the machine model to learn the phenomenon?

Comment: It's probably referring to parametric methods such as maximum likelihood estimation. For example, for a simple binary state Bernoulli distribution, the MLE can be calculated by the derivative of the likelihood (or log likelihood).

Comment: You should probably do your own research until you have a specific example that you can ask about. This is too vague to answer without knowing what kind of machine learning algorithm

Comment: @Alborz Can you please point me to some literature? I did not find any resource that explains how probability theory is used in machine learning. This is one reason for posting this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, starting from a known distribution is not that meaningful in terms of machine learning. We don't need machine learning or any additional method if we already know the samples are following some given PDF.

What we are interested is, estimating the distribution that the sample is following. An easy example is parametric estimation. Suppose that the sample is drawn from some distribution that obeys a known model, let's say  $Bernoulli(p)$. Then estimating the probability $p$ is enough for estimating the entire distribution.

Notice that the PDF of $Bernoulli(p)$ is $P(x)=p^x(1-p)^{1-x}$ for $x\in \{0,1\}$. Given an i.i.d sample $\chi=\{x^t\}_{t=1}^{N}$ where $x^t\in \{0,1\}$,
we can estimate the parameter $p$ by maximizing the log likelihood subject to the parameter $p$
$$L(p|\chi)=\log\prod_{t=1}^{N} p^{x_t}(1-p)^{1-x^t}=\sum_{t=1}^{N} x^t\cdot\log p+(N-\sum_{t=1}^{N} x^t) \log (1-p)$$
and $\frac{dL}{dp}=0$ gives the estimation $$\hat p=\frac{\sum_{t=1}^{N} x^t}{N}$$
and we have estimated the distribution of the sample $\chi$.

Comment: Parameter estimation can only be used after the type of the density function has been  identified. So, a machine learning algorithm first identifies the probability density function of the sample? Does it have a collection of density functions to identify the density function of the sample?

Comment: @AdnanAli This is just a very simple example. Estimating the distribution of the sample is a part of machine learning, but there are much more fields. If we talk about parametric estimation, we **assume** that the sample is following some known distribution (mostly Gaussian). These methods can be also used in classification and regression if we assume that some distribution is following Gaussian, which are the most basic machine learning tasks.